# postgresql - filter out double rows (but not the first and last one)

Tags: sql, postgresql

i got an "postgres" SQL problem.

I got a table which looks like this

```
  id          name          level          timestamp 
   1          pete          1              100 
   2          pete          1              200 
   3          pete          1              500 
   4          pete          5              900 
   7          pete          5              1000 
   9          pete          5              1200 
  15          pete          2              700
```

Now I want to delete the lines i dont need. i only want to now the first line where he get a new level and the last line he has this level.

```
  id          name          level          timestamp 
   1          pete          1              100 
   3          pete          1              500 
  15          pete          2              700 
   4          pete          5              900 
   9          pete          5              1200
```

(there much more columns like realmpoints and so on)

I have a solution if the the timestamp is only increasing.

```
SELECT id, name, level, timestamp 
FROM player_testing 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(dup.id)
              FROM player_testing As dup
              GROUP BY dup.name, dup.level)
              UNION
              SELECT MIN(dup.id)
              FROM player_testing As dup
              GROUP BY dup.name, dup.level)
             )
ORDER BY ts
```

But I find no way to makes it work for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, name, level, timestamp
from (
  select id,name,level,timestamp,
         row_number() over (partition by name, level order by timestamp) as rn,
         count(*) over (partition by name, level) as max_rn
  from player_testing
) t
where rn = 1 or rn = max_rn;
```

---

Btw: `timestamp` is a horrible name for a column. For one reason because it's a reserved word, but more importantly because it doesn't *document* what the column contains. Is that a `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` a `valid_until_timestamp`, ...?

Comment: in my table is it calles ts ;) i only wrote timestamp to make clear what kind of data is stored in this colum.

Comment: @user3279298 `ts` is even worse to be honest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution to @a_horse_with_no_name's without `over partition`, and thus more generic SQL:

```
select * 
from player_testing as A
where id = (
  select min(id)
  from player_testing as B
  where A.name = B.name
  and A.level = B.level
  )
or    id = (
  select max(id)
  from player_testing as B
  where A.name = B.name
  and A.level = B.level
  )
```

Here is the fiddle to show it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47bd44/1

Comment: nice solution too. but here i have to A.xxx = B.xx every colum. i have a much of them. On a_horse_with_no_name solution i only have to list the colums. the question is, which is faster? i have 2.4 million rows at the time (and only collecting for a few days) first solution take about 3min to find (and after modification) delete the unwanted (double) rows. i going to test the generic too.

Comment: ok the second one takes extrem long. on a cleaned table (about 150k rows left) the first solution takes about 5 seconds to check that there are no double rows. the second sql query still running (about 15min now). i think because the sql server has to check for every of the 140k row if there are a min and a max with same values (except id, ts) so its about 140k * 2*140k compares. i dont know how over partition works, but its much much faster.